# Which one is the right process to release production?

Tags: version-control

I have been in two different teams before, both use SVN to release the production code.

The first team commit code on the trunk when developing feature, and every week the lead make a release and tag the
product and store the tagged code in another branch.

The second team branch for each big feature, and when the feature was done, the feature will be merged back to the trunk. When the code needs to be released, another branch is created and cloned from the trunk. Some test and bugfix will be done on the branch for the release. After the product is released, the brach will be closed.

Which is better?

Is there a better way to  do version control?

Answer (score 1):

You're near to branch per feature (aka branch-per-task pattern). You maybe want to take a look to the following articles:

- [This article](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/04/integration-strategies.html) talks about different integration (release) strategies,
  with pros and cons:
- [This other](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/08/branch-per-task-workflow-explained.html) explains branch-per-task pattern: